# Number of element in a relation $R$ of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A = \{1,2,...,n\}$, and $R$ be a relation on $A$ (so $R \subset A \times A$)

i) What is the minimal possible number of elements in $R$?

I tried calculating this as just a normal cartesian product which would have $n^2$ within the set. So $R$ would also need $n^2$ number of elements to be a proper subset of $A\times  A$.

ii) What is the maximal possible number of elements in $R$?

I'm a bit more confused by this one, but I think it would have something to do with calculating it as $2^{n^2}$ i.e., if $n$ was $3$ then it would be $2^9$ or $512$ as the maximum number of elements.

Comment: You have no requirements about the relation other than that it is a relation on $A$?  Hint for the first... the empty set is a subset of every set (*and $A\times A$ is itself a set so the empty set is a subset of $A\times A$*)

Comment: As for maximum number... again, consider how many *elements* there are in $A\times A$.  With regards to what you were positing, $2^{n^2}$ that is not the number of elements in a relation, but rather the *total number of different relations possible*.  That is the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @JMoravitz - There are no other requirements no, what I've wrote is everything that was given to me in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be missing some details concerning the definition of a binary relation from a set to another. Let us recall its definition.

> Let $X$ be a set. A **binary relation on $X$** is a subset $R$ of the Cartesian product $X^2$, i.e. $X \times X$.

Note that the any element from $\mathcal{P}(X \times X)$ is a binary relation on $X$. In particular, $\emptyset$ is a legit binary relation on $X$. Since $\emptyset$ has no elements, there is not a minimal number of elements that a subset of $X^2$ must have in order to be a binary relation on $X$.

For the maximal number, the story is quite different. Taking $X = \{i \in \mathbb{N} \colon i \leq n\}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (as in your example), the largest set in $\mathcal{P}(X^2)$ is $X^2$ itself. And note that $X^2$ has $n^2$ elements. No other element of $\mathcal{P}(X^2)$ has this many objects (you can easily check this by yourself). So the maximal number of elements of a subset $R$ of $X^2$ in order for $R$ to a be a binary relation on $X$ is $n^2$.

I hope this helps you with your future study.

***Remark.*** By definition, given any two sets $A$ and $B$, we say that $A$ is a **proper subset of $B$** if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \neq B$.

Comment: So for i) the minimal number of elements would be 1?

Comment: @pc799 the minimal number would be $0$. Since $\emptyset$ as no elements and it is a binary relation on $X$. In short, in your question, if we denote by $|R|$ the size of $R$, you would have $0 \leq |R| \leq n^2$.

Comment: -Thank you, that makes perfect sense

Comment: @pc799 You’re most welcome! Any further doubt in your study, let us know! Good work

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing things here. A relation is nothing but a subset of a Cartesian Product (in set theory at least).
So a relation $R$ on $A$ means that $R$ is a subset of $A\times A$.
You correctly pointed out that the size of a Cartesian product is equal to the product of the sizes (in the finite case at least). Like you wrote, $A\times A$ has $n^2$ elements.

Now,for any $2$ finite sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\subset Y$ it is always true that $|X|\leq|Y|$. And since $\emptyset\subset R$ and $R\subset A\times A$, what can you conclude about the size of $R$?

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I typed the answer on the phone, therefore I tried to minimize MathJax to the necessary minimum.